# Need Assistane in converting django model admin save method to Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need assistance in converting below save_model method on Django Rest Framework
I have this method on my earlier django model admin

## Existing ModelAdmin

```
class JobCategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('remote_addr',)
    list_display = ['job_category','updated_by','updated_at','created_by','created_at','remote_addr',]
    save_as = True

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if change:  #When update
            obj.updated_by = request.user
            obj.updated_at = datetime.now()
            obj.remote_addr = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
        else:     #When Create
            obj.created_by = request.user
            obj.created_at = datetime.now()
            obj.updated_by = request.user
            obj.remote_addr = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
        obj.save()
```

I need to apply this on my DRF method. Currently I am doing like this.

## Serializer

```
class JobCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = JobCategory
        fields = ('job_category', )

    def create(self,validated_data):
        obj =  JobCategory.objects.create(**validated_data)
        obj.created_by = self.context['request'].user
        obj.updated_by = self.context['request'].user
        obj.remote_addr  = self.context['request'].META['REMOTE_ADDR']
        obj.save()
        return obj

    def update(self,instance,validated_data):
        obj = instance
        obj.job_category = validated_data.get('job_category', obj.job_category)
        obj.updated_by = self.context['request'].user
        obj.remote_addr  = self.context['request'].META['REMOTE_ADDR']
        obj.save()
        return obj
```

Here I am not comfortable with update because I need to pass all the data once again which I do not do in my existing modelAdmin method of save_model. Example ob_category field when i update from X to Y I do not want to call this in my update method.

When it is one field it is still acceptable, but if I need to do for a model where it has lets say 20 fields and I update only one field among those so then I need to specify all the field in my update method.

## Model

```
class JobCategory(models.Model):
    job_category   = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=False,null=False, unique=True,help_text="eg: DATASTAGE, CUSTOM_COMMAND" )
    created_by  = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='const_jc_created_by_user',blank=True, null=True, default=None, editable=False)
    updated_by  = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='const_jc_updated_by_user', blank=True, null=True, default=None, editable=False)
    created_at  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    remote_addr = models.CharField(blank=True, default='',max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["job_category"]
        verbose_name_plural = "Job Categories"

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.job_category
```

## view

```
class JobCategoryDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = JobCategory.objects.all()
    serializer_class = JobCategorySerializer
```

Thanks you for your assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When it is one field it is still acceptable, but if I need to do for a model where it has lets say 20 fields and I update only one field among those so then I need to specify all the field in my update method.

This is simply solved with:

```
for attr in ('job_category', ...):
    setattr(obj, attr, validated_data.get(attr, getattr(obj, attr))
```

Note that you could also loop on validated_data.keys() to make it more generic.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. looping through validated_data.keys() worked for me.
#########

        `for attr in validated_data.keys():
            setattr(obj, attr, validated_data.get(attr, getattr(obj, attr))) `  
     
###########